# Add a field in all document inside nested array object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection. Each has a field `studentUnitList` which is Array of object. Inside this we have `studentTopicList` which is again Array of object. Structure of the document is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "", 
    "studentId" : "", 
    "subjectId" : "", 
    "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
    "subjectName" : "", 
    "numberOfVideos" : NumberInt(312), 
    "catalogueId" : "",
    "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(209301), 
    "lastVisitedDate" : ISODate("2019-09-07T16:55:35.862+0000"), 
    "studentCatalogueId" : "", 
    "lastWatchedSubTopic" : {
        "studentUnitId" : "", 
        "studentTopicId" : "", 
        "studentSubTopicId" : "", 
        "videoCompletionInSeconds" : NumberLong(12)
    }, 
    "studentUnitList" : [
        {
            "_id" : "", 
            "unitId" : "", 
            "unitName" : "", 
            "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
            "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(38024), 
            "studentTopicList" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "", 
                    "topicId" : "", 
                    "topicName" : "", 
                    "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
                    "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(2151), 
                    "studentContents" : [
                        {
                            "contentType" : "SUBTOPIC", 
                            "subTopic" : {
                                "_id" : "", 
                                "subTopicId" : "", 
                                "subTopicName" : "", 
                                "pageContentId" : "", 
                                "videoLengthInSeconds" : NumberLong(2151), 
                                "videoCompletionInSeconds" : NumberLong(0), 
                                "videoCompletionPercentage" : 0.0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "", 
                    "topicId" : "", 
                    "topicName" : "", 
                    "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
                    "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(1903), 
                    "studentContents" : [
                        {
                            "contentType" : "SUBTOPIC", 
                            "subTopic" : {
                                "_id" : "", 
                                "subTopicId" : "", 
                                "subTopicName" : "", 
                                "pageContentId" : "", 
                                "videoLengthInSeconds" : NumberLong(491), 
                                "videoCompletionInSeconds" : NumberLong(0), 
                                "videoCompletionPercentage" : 0.0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a boolean field "active" to each and every object of `studentUnitList`, `studentTopicList`, `subTopic`.
After adding field document will look like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "", 
    "studentId" : "", 
    "subjectId" : "", 
    "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
    "subjectName" : "", 
    "numberOfVideos" : NumberInt(312), 
    "catalogueId" : "",
    "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(209301), 
    "lastVisitedDate" : ISODate("2019-09-07T16:55:35.862+0000"), 
    "studentCatalogueId" : "", 
    "lastWatchedSubTopic" : {
        "studentUnitId" : "", 
        "studentTopicId" : "", 
        "studentSubTopicId" : "", 
        "videoCompletionInSeconds" : NumberLong(12)
    }, 
    "studentUnitList" : [
        {
            "_id" : "", 
            "unitId" : "", 
            "unitName" : "", 
            "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
            "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(38024), 
            "active": true,
            "studentTopicList" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "", 
                    "topicId" : "", 
                    "topicName" : "", 
                    "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
                    "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(2151), 
                    "active": true,
                    "studentContents" : [
                        {
                            "contentType" : "SUBTOPIC", 
                            "subTopic" : {
                                "_id" : "", 
                                "subTopicId" : "", 
                                "subTopicName" : "", 
                                "pageContentId" : "", 
                                "active": true,
                                "videoLengthInSeconds" : NumberLong(2151), 
                                "videoCompletionInSeconds" : NumberLong(0), 
                                "videoCompletionPercentage" : 0.0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "", 
                    "topicId" : "", 
                    "topicName" : "", 
                    "completionPercentage" : 0.0, 
                    "totalVideoLengthInSec" : NumberLong(1903), 
                    "active": true,
                    "studentContents" : [
                        {
                            "contentType" : "SUBTOPIC", 
                            "subTopic" : {
                                "_id" : "", 
                                "subTopicId" : "", 
                                "subTopicName" : "", 
                                "pageContentId" : "", 
                                "active": true,
                                "videoLengthInSeconds" : NumberLong(491), 
                                "videoCompletionInSeconds" : NumberLong(0), 
                                "videoCompletionPercentage" : 0.0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a query or aggregation script to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) positional operator, The all positional operator `$[]` indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  $set: {
    "studentUnitList.$[].active": true,
    "studentUnitList.$[].studentTopicList.$[].active": true,
    "studentUnitList.$[].studentTopicList.$[].studentContents.$[].subTopic.active": true
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/StPla6ToIs5)